# how to find value from html using PHP simple html dom parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

HOW TO GET THIS VALUE="NAME" FROM ABOVE CODE

i tried this code

```
<?php
// example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
include('simple_html_dom.php');
// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('sample.html');
$name = $html->find('.input-group #cpBody_txt_Data_UserName', 0)->innertext;
//echo $html->find('.ssoCitizenName #ssolbl_DisplayName', 0)->plaintext;
echo $name
// extract text from HTML

?>
```

```
<input name="ctl00$cpBody$txt_Data_UserName" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="JOHN DOE" maxlength="100" id="cpBody_txt_Data_UserName" tabindex="1" class="form-control">
```

i used this code to show value but getting blank page.

I NEED  value="JOHN DOE" THIS IN output

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getAttribute` function:

```
$name = $html->find('.input-group #cpBody_txt_Data_UserName', 0);
echo $name->getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: thanks this is now working but another field is not showing for gender

Comment: it is another question, open new post